# How to Dynamically Reference Salesforce Campaigns for Environment-Independent Code

Tags: apex, deployment, environment

I'm developing Salesforce code that interacts with a specific campaign. Currently, I have the following snippet, but it is not environment-independent due to hardcoded IDs:

```
if (opp.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'ExampleDeveloperName') {
opportunityWillUpdate.CampaignId = '123xx'; 
opportunityWillUpdate.CampaignExtensionName = '123yy';
```

}

I understand that directly using Campaign IDs (like '123xx') and potentially the 'CampaignExtensionName' can cause conflicts if campaigns are replicated between environments (e.g., development, testing, production).

One way I found is:

```
List<Campaign> matchingCampaigns = [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name = :campaignName];
```

But in case the campaign name is different in different environments, like development and production, this code would fail.

My question is:
What is the best practise to reference a spesific campaign without using hardcoded ID's?
I also don't want to use custom **metadata type**,**custom setting** or **custom labels**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  You have no choice but to use one of those 3 structures.  Custom Metadata Type is probably best.